# Changing Jquery Validator error location makes it show error multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

For some reason when I change the location of the error message [per the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/) it then shows the error multiple times.

It will give the error message when I click the submit button and even when I click somewhere else on the body.

It doesn't replace the error message with the appropriate message it just adds the new error below it.

IMG for reference:

[image]

Looking to get back to the normal functionality but still change the error location.

HTML:

```
<form role="form" id="avoForm" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="input-group input-group-newsletter">
     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email..." aria-label="Enter email..." aria-describedby="basic-addon">
     <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-secondary" name="avoForm" type="submit">Blast Off!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div id="errorct"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#avoForm").validate({
  rules: {
  email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    maxlength: 30
  }
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
   if (element.attr("name") == "email") {
     error.insertAfter("#errorct");
   } else {
     error.insertAfter(element);
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've told the plugin to put the error message container someplace *outside* of your `form` container, thus breaking the plugin's ability to toggle the message properly.

It can easily be fixed by moving your error message into the `<form></form>` container.

```
<form role="form" id="avoForm" action="" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group input-group-newsletter">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email..." aria-label="Enter email..." aria-describedby="basic-addon">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" name="avoForm" type="submit">Blast Off!</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="errorct"></div>
    <!--// dynamic error message will be here - INSIDE FORM //-->

</form>
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/cuzd5zcb/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/cuzd5zcb/1/)**