# Using jquery validate errorPlacement to get error message in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, errorplacement

I am attempting to use jQuery Validate's `errorPlacement` function to place an error message, but I cannot figure it out. Whenever I hit submit, the input slides down, instead of the error placing in the `newsletterValidate` div.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong in my `errorPlacement` code?

[image]

```js
$('#newsletterForm').validate({
  //errorClass: 'invalid',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
   //element.val(error[0].outerText);
   //error.appendTo(element.next('div'));
    error.appendTo(element.parent('div').next('div').find('#newsletterValidate'));
  },
  rules: {
   email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
   }
  },
  messages: {
   email: {
    required: "Please enter your email address",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address"
   }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var datastring = $('#newsletterForm').serialize();
   $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/php/newsletterSend.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: datastring
    ,
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     if (data == 'Error!') {
      alert('Unable to submit form!');
      alert(data);
     } else {
      $('#newsletterInput')[0].reset();
      $('#newsletterSuccess').show();
     }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(textStatus + '|' + errorThrown);
     console.log('error');
    }
   });
  }
 });
```

```css
#newsletterInput {
 width: 70%;
 border: none;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
}
#newsletterSubmit {
 width: 25%;
 display: inline-block;
 border: none;
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id="newsletterForm">
    <input type="email" id="newsletterInput" name="email" placeholder="Email Address *"><input type="submit" id="newsletterSubmit">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="newsletterValidate"></div>
```

Comment: You have to use your browser's DOM inspection tools to see where your message is being placed.  Then adjust your jQuery accordingly.

Comment: You also have to read the jQuery documentation.  `parent()` only traverses up one level.  In your case, there is NO `div` that is an immediate parent of your `input` element.  Try `parents()` instead.

Comment: @Sparky Thank you. I tried `parents`, but it did not help. Also, I do not see where the error is populating in the dom. There error class is being applied to the input though.

Comment: There is no reason to traverse around the DOM hunting for an element when you know its exact `id`, which is already unique to the page.  DOM traversal only makes sense when the page contains many potential targets, like when you want to find a particular element with a class.  **You want an `id` so just target the `id`**.  See detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error.appendTo(element.parent('div').next('div').find('#newsletterValidate'));
```

I'm not sure why you are using jQuery to traverse around inside the DOM when you already know the unique `id`.  So just skip right to your target...

```
error.appendTo($('#newsletterValidate'));
```

Demo 1:  [jsfiddle.net/b2enbs0s/](https://jsfiddle.net/b2enbs0s/)

However, now that it's working, you can see there's a different problem.  [The message is being repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49824729/594235).

That's because you're trying to place the message *outside* of the `form` container...

```
<div>
    <form id="newsletterForm">
        <input type="email" id="newsletterInput" name="email" placeholder="Email Address *"><input type="submit" id="newsletterSubmit">
    </form>
</div>
<!--// outside of the form //-->
<div id="newsletterValidate"></div>
```

In this case, the plugin creates the validation message but cannot find it again in order to properly toggle it.

The fix is to place the message element *inside* of the `form` container where the plugin can automatically find & toggle after it's created.  The following structure visually renders identical to your original layout...

```
<form id="newsletterForm">
    <div>
         <input type="email" id="newsletterInput" name="email" placeholder="Email Address *"><input type="submit" id="newsletterSubmit">
    </div>
    <!--// inside of the form //-->
    <div id="newsletterValidate"></div>
</form>
```

**Final Working Demo:  [jsfiddle.net/b2enbs0s/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/b2enbs0s/1/)**

Comment: Thank you for this. It is perfect. I appreciate the extended answer to with your explanation. One question though. In my question you can see in my illustration that my input is going down once the error triggers. It is still doing this. Do you have any idea why it may be doing this?

Comment: @Paul, my demo does not show that, nor does your live demo above.  Obviously something is being inserted into the DOM at that location or you still have some broken HTML.  Use your browser's live DOM inspection tool to find it.  Otherwise, you'll have to provide the actual code that reproduces this issue.